# Mac terminal font changes on external monitor

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, terminal, fonts

I have a Dell U2412M Monitor that I connect to my 2015 Macbook Pro with a DVI to Thunderbolt connector.

When I open and view the Terminal on my laptop's screen, the terminal looks like this:

[image: laptop terminal]

This is how I want it to look. Specifically, it uses Monaco as the display font. However, when I move the same terminal window over to my external monitor, it looks like this:

[image: external monitor terminal]

The font has completely changed.

Why?

Comment: That looks like the original/classic Monaco 12 pt (?) bitmap that the TrueType outline font was based on. It probably has something to do with the fact that the Dell monitor is not a Retina display. Not sure why it isn't anti-aliased though.

Comment: I suspect Spiff is correct, as the first image has a DPI of 144, while the second is 72.  Additionally, they use different ColorSync profiles.

Comment: Any way to achieve the opposite? My terminal opens with the crisp Terminus font on the external screen, but if I drag it to laptop screen and back, the font changes irrevocably to a poor-looking one (not as poor as in your case, though.) Anti-aliasing does change appearance of both, but seems orthogonal.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I solved it this way:

1. Go to Terminal
2. Preferences
3. Profiles (select your profile)
4. Text
5. Check **Antialias text**

[image: Check antialias text option]

Comment: This definitely works (and feels *so* good) - but why isn't it turned on by default? Is it a performance concern?

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much!